# Opening a sheet, copying and pasting into a template sheet issue

Tags: excel, vba

I get sent a spreadsheet from a customer at work once a week, I am trying to write some vba to open it copy and paste the data in there into my template and then save and close the customer file to a new folder.My process so far is that I save the file to a specific folder, then I run my macro/vba script and it opens the file copies all the data over but then I cant figure out how to reference the customer sheet and close it and save it to a new file path. I am referencing the file paths in the code to ranges as well.

Here is what I have tried so far. I still cant figure this out to reference back to the sheet without referencing the sheets actual name which I do not want to do as the sheet name will change once a week.

```
Sub OpenFileInFolder()

Dim ThisFolder As String
Dim ThisFile As String
Dim PathName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Filename As String

'specify folder location and type of files to open in folder
ThisFolder = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("settings").Range("rngFileLocation").Value
ThisFile = Dir(ThisFolder & "\*.xlsx")

    'open the xlsx file in folder
    If ThisFile <> "" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisFolder & "\" & ThisFile)
        
        ThisFile = Dir
    End If
    
   ' copy data from file

    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    ' paste data into template
    Windows("Testing.xlsm").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    ' save and close workbook
    PathName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("settings").Range("rngArchivePath")

    Filename = ThisWorkbook.Name
    
    sfName = PathName & "\" & Filename
   
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sfName, _
        FileFormat:=xlsx, CreateBackup:=False
        
    Workbooks(Filename & ".xlsx").Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you copying everything or is there something not copied? Where exactly do you want to move the source file i.e. maybe it's somehow related to the paths used already? Or is it the destination file (the one containing this code) that you want to save somewhere else? Or do you want to export just the `Data` sheet to another location? What is the name of the worksheet in the source file (`wb`) or is it maybe the first sheet i.e. are you sure the correct one will be selected?

Answer (score 0):

### Import Worksheet and Move File to Backup Location

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportCustomerSheet()

    ' Destination Workbook
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Destination Lookup Worksheet
    Dim dlws As Worksheet: Set dlws = dwb.Sheets("Settings")
    ' Retrieve the source folder path and the source backup path.
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = dlws.Range("rngFileLocation").Value
    Dim sBackupPath As String: sBackupPath = dlws.Range("rngArchivePath").Value
    
    ' Destination Paste Worksheet
    Dim dpws As Worksheet: Set dpws = dwb.Sheets("Data")
    
    ' Source File Name
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "\*.xlsx")
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The customer file was not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Source File Path
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = sFolderPath & "\" & sFileName
    
    ' Source Workbook
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
    ' Source Worksheet
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.ActiveSheet
    ' better is Set sws = swb.Sheets("Sheet1") or at least ...Sheets(1)
    
    ' Copy.
    sws.UsedRange.Copy dpws.Range("A1")
    ' Close.
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Copy the source file to the backup path.
    FileCopy sFilePath, sBackupPath & "\" & sFileName
    ' Delete the source file.
    'Kill sFilePath
     
    ' Maybe...
    'dwb.Save
     
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Customer sheet imported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```